# When to use the nouns: Managers, Adapters, Handlers

Tags: c#, .net

A newbie question.

What are the useCases to call your classes with postfix Managers, Adapters, Handlers?
Are there any other common nouns to use?

Thanks

Comment: Surely just naming it after what it does is the best "pattern"? If it manages something, name it SomethingManager, if it handles something, name it SomethingHandler, if it wibbles something, name it SomethingWibbler.

Comment: I sometimes use the "Repository" suffix for something that holds data.